# How to align image at extreme left of listitem?

Tags: android, image, listitem

I have an ImageView (android:id="@+id/unreadmail) which i want to show on extreme left of ListItem as shown in image. But it is not aligning properly. Any idea if i am missing anything ?

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailsubject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="abcd"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailcontent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/emailsubject"
        android:layout_below="@id/emailsubject"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="defg"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/unreademail"
    android:layout_width="2dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/emailsubject"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#8A6175"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rcvdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="20dip"
    android:textColor="#313132"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".MainActivity"
 tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,ContentDescription,UselessLeaf,UselessParent" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/unreademail"
        android:layout_width="15dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailsubject"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="abcd"
            android:textColor="#444444"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailcontent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/emailsubject"
            android:layout_below="@id/emailsubject"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="defg"
            android:textColor="#444444"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rcvdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Piyush, it is giving me date below subtitle where as date has to be on extreme right as that of image which is there on extreme left

Comment: Thanks...But answer needs to be really improved as you can never define height to any of the items...it will never give good result :) Thanks for approach

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using a relative layout at the top level (possibly not included in your code). 
You cannot use 'to the left of' when the elements are at different levels in the heirarchy.

Thus I would start with your little icon left aligned to the parent and put the edit box (in the same relative view) 'to the right of' the icon.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code sample for you there is no need to write the weight property if add the screenshot or the supported image how exactly you want then i can give you proper answer

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/unreademail"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailsubject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="abcd"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailcontent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/emailsubject"
        android:layout_below="@id/emailsubject"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="defg"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/unreademail"
    android:layout_width="2dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#8A6175"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rcvdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="20dip"
    android:textColor="#313132"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Too many mistakes...You can still improve answer by trying it once from your side